# Transform Excel VBA in a Web-Service function

Tags: web-services, excel, sharepoint, vba

I am working on a project, that has Excel VBA code.
We need to execute the VBA code concurrently (Excel has not be modified between executions).
NOTE: The VBA code is called by another system.

***Goal: transform Excel VBA code in a web-service function***

The first idea was put the Excel on Sharepoint, but this is not a choice as we can see on: http://community.office365.com/en-us/w/officeapps/excel-workbooks-with-macros-do-not-open-in-excel-online/revision/2.aspx

Is Excel Calculation Services our solution? I never heard about that
https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc263457%28v=office.12%29.aspx

**Another option without Excel:** discard the Excel and construct the Web-Service logic in an OOP language (like Java), the only trouble about that is the reverse engineering on a very complex Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your circumstances, its true that VBA won't work in a web view of an excel file on sharepoint, but if you open the file in excel the VBA macro should work fine.
If the macro needs to access network resources via sharepoint where you don't have webDAV access to the share then its more tricky but can be done.

Can you clarify your situation.